# Refresh destination schema metadata in Integration Services

Tags: ssis, refresh, metadata

I have been working on a huge ETL project with 150+ tables and during the design I had to make a major change on destination column names and data types for a couple of tables.

My problem is that I can't get SSIS to see the new schema for the tables I changed. So I would like to know **how can I get SSIS to refresh this schema?** I find it kind of ridiculous that there no way to tell SSIS to update the metadata from database schema, especially for database migration.

Recreating the project from scratch is out of question because I already spent some hours on it. Also changing manually the 400+ columns I changed is also not an option.

Comment: This one probably won't solve your problem but it can help. Entire SSIS package is just xml. You can change xml data using "Find and Replace" or create your own tool. If you want to track changes in SSIS you have to use UDM ( Data Source Views ).

Comment: I actually looked into my package XML before but there was way too much columns to change so even a find/replace could not fix it due to the specificity of some changes. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following my previous auto-answer, I finally found what was preventing the metadata from being refreshed.

When I originally modified my database, I actually executed another script that was making a `DROP` on the table and then a `CREATE TABLE` to recreate the table from scratch. There, SSIS was never able to detect changes and I had to do all the things in my other answer.

Later today I had to make some minor modification and this time I opted for an `ALTER TABLE`. Magically, this time SSIS detected all the changes even notifying me to refresh columns from the advanced editor, which worked fine.

So basically all these issues has been caused by my poor knowledge about DBA and its best practices.

Answer (score 19):

What about using the `Advanced Editor` and pressing the `Refresh` button on the left side below?

Comment: Stupidly simple but did the job for me!

Comment: @Fishcake -- Something this stupidly simple should be on the non-Advanced (e.g., the Normal) editor. I don't know why Microsoft thought it was a good idea to hide a bunch of, in my opinion (and I assume many others' opinions), BASIC functionality behind an Advanced editor.

Answer (score 3):

I found a way to fix it but that was a bit tricky.

Even thought I was completely removing any references of the table from my packages, I was always getting the old metadata.

I still don't have a clear fix but here is what I did to fix it:

- Removed any reference to concerned source and destination tables
- Deleted obj and bin folder from the project folder
- Saved, closed and then reopened the project
- Created new data flow from scratch and updated metadata was finally there

Don't know where those informations were cached but I suspect that the obj folder keeps a cached copy of your packages or that Visual Studio keeps metadata in memory which is freed when you close it. Anyway, following these steps should fix it.

Comment: I think if you open the destination component and go to the mapping tab, it should pick up the new metadata. That usually works for me.

Comment: That is the first thing I did but it was always giving me the old metadata.