# BIGINT to INT conversion in Terada

Tags: sql-server, ssis, int, teradata, bigint

I'm trying to load BIGINT column (A) data from teradata to INT column(A) in sql server using SSIS package.

I tried data conversion, it didn't work. Thought of limiting data to `INT` in teradata side. I got the following error:

> numeric overflow occurred during computation error.

Also, I tried to recreate SQL server table column with bigint datatype, it didn't work as getting error while running Processing engine as it's configured int datatype for that column. please let me know if there is any way i can use to solve this issue? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think that the recreating the SQL destination table with BIGINT data type should work. But you have to make sure that the metadata is updated in the SSIS package.

- [Refresh destination schema metadata in Integration Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10976511/refresh-destination-schema-metadata-in-integration-services)
- [How to refresh database schema metadata?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/50bfe749-7b88-4ee6-8e5d-15dafbc63f71/how-to-refresh-database-schema-metadata?forum=sqlintegrationservices)